# Grails - Could not create a new instance of class [QuartzGrailsPlugin]!

Tags: grails, groovy, jvm

I just started using Grails and I need to make an svn downloaded grails project to work.

But when I try and run in, I get this error:

```
Error loading plugin manager: Could not create a new instance of class [QuartzGrailsPlugin]!
```

I tried with different version of ggts (lastone and 3.5) and jdk (1.6-1.7-1.8).

When Creating a very simple project from scratch, it works.

here is the full console:

```
2015-09-30 11:52:53,068 [main] DEBUG converters.StringConverter  - Converting 'String' value 'stdout' to type 'String'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [QuartzGrailsPlugin]!
at _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure5_closure40.doCall(_PluginDependencies_groovy:270)
at _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure5_closure40.doCall(_PluginDependencies_groovy)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
at _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_PluginDependencies_groovy:268)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:167)
at _GrailsWar_groovy$_run_closure4.doCall(_GrailsWar_groovy:91)
at War$_run_closure1.doCall(War.groovy:38)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/quartz/TaskArtefactHandler : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
at QuartzGrailsPlugin.class$(QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy)
at QuartzGrailsPlugin.$get$$class$org$codehaus$groovy$grails$plugins$quartz$TaskArtefactHandler(QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy)
at QuartzGrailsPlugin.<init>(QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy:61)
... 19 more

Error loading plugin manager: Could not create a new instance of class [QuartzGrailsPlugin]!
```

I also run the app from command line doing this:

```
grails run-app
```

with the exact same result.

Comment: Dies it with from the command line?

Comment: I tried with ggts only

Comment: I think @tim_yates is suggesting you *try* it with command line, and see if that has the same issue.  He's trying to suggest it might be a GGTS issue, rather than a Grails issue.

Comment: I tried with right click on project run-app, is it not the same? please how shall I do by command line? typing "grails" in cmd does not recognize the command

Comment: I edited my question with more info including the command line

Comment: try disabling the quartz plugin from the config file and start troubleshooting from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using INtellij Idea. I've faced same problem. I'd chanded my java sdk to 1.6. then execute clean-all command. Then compile.

It worked for me.